# Add URL to Pie-Donut Highchart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How can one add URL support in a donut Highchart? I tried but I get undefined error in URL. Your help would be highly appreciated.

This is what I added in the series

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: function(e) {
      location.href = e.point.url;
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}

data = [{
      y: 55.11,
      color: colors[0],
      url: 'www.google.com', 
      drilldown: {
         name: 'MSIE versions',
         categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
         data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
         url: 'www.google.com',
         color: colors[0]
      }
}, { .......many more dataset ...
```

*Updated:*

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxskW/3/) example of donut chart

Comment: What do you mean with "URL support"?

Comment: I mean when I click on the pie it should take me to the URL set in the individual pie. Updated the example with `data` field showing `url: 'www.google.com',`

Comment: JSFiddle not working.

Answer (score 2):

**[check out this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/y6XQA/)**

this is the method i use for a highcharts instance with added links to data urls.

when instantiating a new highchart, you will want to set your cursor to pointer (to let users know they can click things) and you additionally want to setup a point click event as follows:

```
   plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        location.href = this.options.url;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

each element in your series > data should also now contain a 'url' key value pair as follows:

```
series: [{
    data: [{
        y: 29.9,
        url: 'http://bing.com/search?q=foo'
    }, { ... // more data sets
```

Comment: Does not work. Check this URL [Update code] (http://jsfiddle.net/sxskW/3/). This code has link to `www.google.com` with two different methods 1) `click: function(e) {
                            location.href = e.point.url;
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }` 2) `click: function() {
                            location.href = this.options.url;
                        }` -- Gives 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) In your series object I don't see anywhere options url.

2) Path should be `e.point.series.options.url;`

Working code:

```
        {
            name: 'Browsers',
            url: "http://www.google.com", // add url 1)
            data: browserData,
            size: '60%',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function(e) {
                        location.href = e.point.series.options.url; //proper path 2)
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                },
                color: 'white',
                distance: -30
            }
        }
```

And jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sxskW/6/ (doesn't redirect because of X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN).

Comment: It is an old topic, jsFiddle during last 2.5 years list some of the demos. Anyway, code posted in the answer works.